# missing android.jar in visual studio 2013

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to use mono for android in vs.net 2013.
when running the project, it says:

Error   1   Could not find android.jar for API Level 8. This means the Android SDK platform for API Level 8 is not installed. Either install it in the Android SDK Manager (Tools > Open Android SDK Manager...), or change your Xamarin.Android project to target an API version that is installed. (C:\Users\M.K_Soft\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-8\android.jar missing.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Visual Studio, there is a shortcut icon to open the SDK Manager (see picture below).

[image]

Then simply install the missing API Level 8 that your error is missing.

[image]

This should fix it.

Comment: It said I was missing API 21. So I installed it. Didn't work. Do I need to restart my computer or something? I restarted VS...

Comment: @vbullinger We have had problems with me and my colleague running the Alpha channel mode and a new colleague running a Stable channel mode (in the Xamarin Studio > Help > Check for Updates). We ended up changing to Stable and installing Android 5.0 API 21. But you may have to play with it. I know that the Android L Preview API shows as "20, L", but can sometimes to labelled 21 in the actual SDK folder, which will conflict with the Android 5.0 API 21.

Comment: Seems like mine, in particular, was a bug that was fixed in a recent beta, so I just installed that and I'm back up and running

Comment: @vbullinger Glad you are fixed. I think the Android L Preview and the latest Android 5.0 was quite buggy together. :-(

Answer (score 2):

If you have installed any other API before, you can set your project to compile using that API. for this you need to right click on you project and go to Properties section. In Properties section go to application tab, and set "Compile using Android version" to the version that you have installed it before. Note that this option is set to API 8 by default, and you need to change it based on your installed APIs
[image]

If these things are normal, then you may need to check this address to see if your API exists there too :

```
C:\Users\[Your User]\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platforms\
```

If the required api is not exists here then you may need to copy it from address below:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms\
```

I hope these will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

try to Delete Package then re- Install Package again ..

Answer (score 0):

You can get `android.jar` file from `https://github.com/Sable/android-platforms` and just paste it into the location that is shown in bash.
This will work fine on Windows, Linux and may be on Mac(haven't tried yet).